# toggling the focus from button to Text box using enter key to which an event is binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$('#b').on('click', function() {
  $('#in2').focus();
  //setTimeout(function(){ $('#in2').focus(); },500); 
});
$('#in2').on('keyup', function(event) {
  console.log(event.which);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="b">focus</button>
<input type="text" id="in1" />
<input type="text" id="in2" />
```

I have a key up function bound to button where I am shifting my focus to text field `#in2` in the above example.

And I also have a key down event bound for text field `#in2`.

**Problem**: When I am using the enter key on the button, event bound to the text field(`#in2`) is getting called.

Can someone suggest me some solution except setTimeout?

Comment: Please try to use full sentences with correct grammer (as good as possible). That helps people understand your problem.

Comment: I don't see a key up funktion bound to the button. The key up function is bound to text field 2. There is no key down function at all in your code. Pressing the button will make text field 2 get the focus.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly and you don't want the function on keyup on #in2 called when Enter is pressed, just check whether the pressed key is enter and only execute it if it isn't?

```
$('#in2').on('keyup', function(event) {
  if(event.which != 13){
    console.log(event.which);
  }
});
```

Alternatively you could use onchange so that the function gets called when the content of the element changes (this would also work with copy-and-past for example)